# Getting the size of each partition in a CosmosDB collection

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Is it possible to get the size of **every** partition in a Cosmos DB collection? I know the portal will show the top few partitions in a collection, in the Metrics blade, but I'm interesting in seeing the size of every partition.

Comment: I'm still looking for more information in this area as well.  So far what I've done is write 20K documents and then look at my test partition size in the Azure portal cosmosDB metrics.  For mine, it's about 1M for every 1K documents.  I can extrapolate size from that as long as I can get a count of documents from the partition (assuming you have the same document schema throughout the partition).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should be able to get this data through the Cosmos DB REST API.

It doesn't seem to be exposed through the .NET SDK so you'd need to write some C# or PowerShell yourself to access the data however, it should be available.

Link is:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db-resource-provider/collectionpartition/listusages